# No change of records after creating relationships between two nodes

Tags: neo4j

```
CREATE (a:User{Name:'Jennifer', Age:12,Gender:'Female', Email:'Jennifer@gmail.com'}) 
,(b:User{Name: 'Johnnason', Age:16,Gender:'Male', Email:’Johnnason@gmail.com'})


MATCH (a:User),(b:User)
WHERE a.name = 'Jennifer' AND b.name = 'Johnnason'
CREATE (a)-[r:RELTYPE{ name: a.name + 'is friend with' + b.name }]->(b)
RETURN type(r)
```

Here is the code. I am trying to build a mutual relationship called between Jennifer and Johnnason. However The result I got is (no changes, no records).

Comment: It's because your MATCHes fail. You're looking for :User nodes with certain `name` properties, but the nodes you created don't have `name` properties, they have `Name` properties, the cases don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed small typo in your queries. also changed the return type for the second query to return the relationship itself, instead of the relationship type.  works now.

```
CREATE (a:User{Name:'Jennifer', Age:12,Gender:'Female', Email:'Jennifer@gmail.com'}) ,
(b:User{Name: 'Johnnason', Age:16,Gender:'Male', Email:'Johnnason@gmail.com'})


MATCH (a:User), (b:User) 
WHERE a.Name = 'Jennifer' AND b.Name = 'Johnnason'
CREATE (a)-[r:RELTYPE{ name: a.Name + ' is friend with ' + b.Name }]->(b)
RETURN (r)
```